# multiple catch block and continue operator

Tags: java

I faced an issue using multi-catch blocks with an exceptions which can be applied to the same event. Please take a look at the code below:

```
for (String currentString : stringsList) {
    try {
        Long.valueOf(currentString);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //do smth;
        continue; 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do smth;
        continue;
    }
    //do smth; 
}
```

The idea is the following: if the current string variable is `null` then particular actions are performed and the current iteration is finished without checking for `NumberFormatException`. But it turnes out when the `currentString == null` the next catch-block is fulfilled anyway. I can't understand why `continue` doesn't work in this case and the first catch-block is not left. The next solution is not acceptable because it doesn't let fulfill the code remain in the loop:

```
for (String currentString : stringsList) {
    try {
        Long.valueOf(currentString);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //do smth;
        break; 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do smth;
    } finally {
        continue;
    }
    //do smth; 
}
```

I found the solution but it is not elegant:

```
for (String currentString : stringsList) {
    if (currentString == null) {
        //do smth;
        continue;
    }

    try {
        Long.valueOf(currentString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do smth;
        continue;
    }
    //do smth; 
}
```

If anyone have an idea how to solve it I would really appreciate an advice. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** 
Really sorry but it was my fault. Long.valueOf(null) throws NumberFormatException also. Thanks for all the comments. My current solution is:

```
 for (String currentString : stringsList) {
        try {
            Long.valueOf(currentString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (currentString != null) {
                //do smth;
            }
            continue;         
        }
        //do smth;
 }
```

Comment: *the next catch-block is fulfilled anyway* -- If a `NullPointerException` is caught, the next `catch` block will *not* run. There's most likely something else wrong with your code. (If you don't agree with me, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: catching the NullPointerException is IMHO a bad idea, your "not elegant" solution is better actually.

Comment: Your code can only raise one kind of exception: If you get NPE, then you can not have NFE also, so using `continue` in both catch blocks won't skip any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long.valueOf doesn't throw NullPointerException.

In the Long source code you will see that the valueOf method calls the parseLong method.

This method checks for null and throws a NumberFormatException (see code snippet below)

```
public static long parseLong(String s, int radix)
          throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (s == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    }
```

So you will have to do this

```
if (currentString == null) {
    //do smth;
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, your explanation is not very clear but looking at your "not-so-elegant" example, you can have something as below.
If all the "//do smth;" code is same then have a common method, else have it separately but try to keep all common code in one place. You should not have duplicate code.
If those pieces of code is reusable from other classes then create a utility class and put it as public method.

**Considering all your `//do smth;` is different**

```
private void yourMethod(){
            for (String currentString : stringsList) {
                if (currentString == null) {
                    //do smth;
                } else{
                    try {
                        Long.valueOf(currentString);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        //do smth;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //do smth;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Considering all your `//do smth;` is same**

```
private void yourMethod(){
            for (String currentString : stringsList) {
                if (currentString == null) {
                    doSomething();
                } else{
                    try {
                        Long.valueOf(currentString);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        //Error handling...
                    } finally{
                        doSomething();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void doSomething(){
            //do smth;
        }
```